# How do I know if Universal Membership Providers are installed on my host?

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am going to be developing a new web app using MVC 4.  It will be hosted on a shared server (one of those $5/month sites:  sqlservermart.com)

It has been a few years, and it looks like there is a new "Universal Membership Provider" instead of the old membership provider.  My question is can I assume that the universal membership providers will be available if .NET 4.0 is on the remote server?  If not, what are the providers installed as part of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

universal providers are not installed with .NET Fx. Its a nuget package which you will have to install in your project. when you publish your project to the remote server you will have to publish the universal provider dll which would be in the bin of your application
http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core